# Angular 2 Child Routes Not Working As Expected

Tags: routes, angular, parent-child

I've got an app using A2's router (angular2@2.0.0-beta.13) and I am trying to get child routes working but getting something strange. When the app loads, the structure in the dev window looks like this:

```
<application>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <undefined>
        <div class="metrics-header">...</div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <undefined>
            <div class="metrics-header">...</div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <div class="metrics-footer">...</div>
        </undefined>
        <div class="metrics-footer">...</div>
    </undefined>
<application>
```

ApplicationComponent (Parent):

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {LoginComponent} from '../login/login.component';
import {MetricsComponent} from '../metrics/metrics.component';

import {EmitterService} from '../../services/emitter/emitter.service';

@Component({
    selector:'application',
    styleUrls:['./app/components/application/application.component.css'],
    templateUrl:'./app/components/application/application.component.html',
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS, EmitterService]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path:'../login', name:'Login', component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'../metrics/...', name:'Metrics', component:MetricsComponent, useAsDefault:true}
    ])

export class ApplicationComponent{

    emitter = EmitterService.get("LoginChannel");

    constructor(
        private _router: Router
    ){
        this.emitter.subscribe(data => this.navigateTo(data));
    }

    navigateTo(view){
        console.log('navigateTo(' + view + ')');
        this._router.navigate([view]);
    }
}
```

ApplicationComponent Template:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

MetricsComponent (Child):

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {Subscription}   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import {TouchGesturesService} from '../../services/touch-gestures/touch-gestures.service';
import {MetricsService} from '../../services/metrics/metrics.service';
import {EmitterService} from '../../services/emitter/emitter.service';

import {DatacardsComponent} from '../datacards/datacards.component';

@Component({
    styleUrls:['./app/components/metrics/metrics.component.css'],
    templateUrl:'./app/components/metrics/metrics.component.html',
    providers: [EmitterService, MetricsService, TouchGesturesService, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, EmitterService],
    directives:[DatacardsComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/pastYear', name: 'PastYear', component: DatacardsComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/pastMonth', name: 'PastMonth', component: DatacardsComponent },
    { path: '/dailyAverage', name: 'DailyAverage', component: DatacardsComponent },
])

export class MetricsComponent implements OnInit{

    emitter = EmitterService.get('LoginChannel');

    subscription: Subscription;

    public pages = ['Past Year', 'Past Month', 'Daily Average'];
    public currentPage = 0;

    startCoords = { x: null, y: null };
    currentCoords = { x: null, y: null };
    endCoords = { x: null, y: null, swipe: null };

    screen = { w: null, h: null };

    constructor(
        private _touchGesturesService: TouchGesturesService,
        private _router: Router
    ){
        this.screen = {
            w: window.innerWidth,
            h: window.innerHeight
        }
        console.log('Window Width: ' + this.screen.w);
        console.log('Window Height: ' + this.screen.h);
        this.swipeMetrics(null);
    }

    swipeMetrics(swipeDirection){
        switch (swipeDirection) {
            case 'left':
                console.log('swiping left');
                console.log('incoming view: ' + this.pages[this.currentPage].replace(' ', ''))
                this._router.navigate([this.pages[this.currentPage].replace(' ', '')]);
                break;
            case 'right':
                console.log('swiping right');
                console.log('incoming view: ' + this.pages[this.currentPage].replace(' ', ''))
                this._router.navigate([this.pages[this.currentPage].replace(' ', '')]);
                break;
            default:
                //console.log('not swiping');
                break;
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(){
    }

    swipeStart(){
        this.startCoords = this._touchGesturesService.swipeStart();
        //console.log('startCoords: ' + this.startCoords.x + ' | ' + this.startCoords.y);
    }
    swipeMove(){
        this.currentCoords = this._touchGesturesService.swipeMove();
        //console.log('currentCoords: ' + this.currentCoords.x + ' | ' + this.currentCoords.y);
    }
    swipeEnd(){
        this.endCoords = this._touchGesturesService.swipeEnd();
        var cp = this.currentPage;
        //console.log('swiped ' + this.endCoords.swipe.direction);
        switch (this.endCoords.swipe.direction) {
            case 'left':
                cp++;
                if(cp < this.pages.length){
                    this.currentPage = cp;
                }else{
                    //console.log('reset currentPage to 0');
                    this.currentPage = 0;
                }
                //console.log('currentPage: ' + this.currentPage);
                this.swipeMetrics('left');
                break;
            case 'right':
                cp--;
                if(cp < 0){
                    //console.log('reset currentPage to ' + (this.pages.length - 1));
                    this.currentPage = this.pages.length - 1;
                }else{
                    this.currentPage = cp;
                }
                //console.log('currentPage: ' + this.currentPage);
                this.swipeMetrics('right');
                break;
        }
        //console.log('endCoords: ' + this.endCoords.x + ' | ' + this.endCoords.y + ' (' + this.endCoords.swipe.direction + ')');
    }

    isCurrentPage(page){
        return (page === this.currentPage) ? true : false;
    }

    reload(){
        window.location.href = '/application-starter-kit/src';
    }

    logout(){
        // need logoout functionality after login is fully implemented
        this.emitter.emit('Login');
    }
}
```

MetricsComponent Template:

```
    <div class="metrics-header">
        <div (click)="logout()">Logout</div>
        <div>{{ pages[currentPage] }}</div>
        <div><a (click)="reload()">Reload</a></div>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div class="metrics-footer">
        <div></div>
        <div class="current-page">
            <div *ngFor="#page of pages; #i=index" [class.selected]="isCurrentPage(i)"></div>
        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
```

One other note: Due to the structure of the app at the moment, I've had to use ../ on the parent RouteConfig for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `..` in front of the paths

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/login', name:'Login', component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'/metrics/...', name:'Metrics', component:MetricsComponent, useAsDefault:true}
    ])
```

and for the child routes add a `/`

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/pastYear', name: 'PastYear', component: DatacardsComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/pastMonth', name: 'PastMonth', component: DatacardsComponent },
    { path: '/dailyAverage', name: 'DailyAverage', component: DatacardsComponent },
])
```

The Angular2 router is hierarchical and for the current router the paths are root level paths.

Comment: Doing the above gives me a terminal loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal loop"?

Comment: Sorry. Infinite loop.I've updated the post to include the full code for both components.

Comment: Here is a similar simplified example https://plnkr.co/edit/up1gsT?p=preview Can you try to update the code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Also updated the post to show the corresponding templates and a simple example of the end result (same content loaded into both router-outlets.)

Comment: Have you checked the Plunker? Most if not all seems unrelated to the problem. Try to reproduce in a Plunker with as few code as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111119/discussion-between-eric-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Initial version here. I am getting the "loading..." every time I try to use the router setup. (This is the first time I've used Plunker, by the way.) https://plnkr.co/edit/VIoI1RHEaUrTAJQY1JV9

Comment: It was a rc.0 Plunker with beta.x code. Use https://plnkr.co/edit/wnLWAW?p=preview instead

Comment: Thanks. Updated it to here; https://plnkr.co/edit/M6iSqSORhXtLXKWZkshC?p=preview, and it breaks when trying to get the navigation in MetricsComponent. Just to clarify, the navigation interaction for the ApplicationComponent and MetricsComponent are independent of each other and control only their respective child views.

Comment: If you use a leading `/` in router link (`['/Xxx']`) then the router starts at the root component but the router links in `MetricsComponent` are supposed to be routed at the current level. https://plnkr.co/edit/cTUAlOH2pb8T3tMW9MPF?p=preview

Comment: Okay. Working on a single page in Plunker, but when I made these updates to my app, I am still getting MetricsComponent in both the ApplicationComponent router-outlet and the MetricsComponent router-outlet. When I try to navigate, I get 'Component "ApplicationComponent" has no route named "PastYear".'

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see a way to help you when I have no way to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate your patience. I'm wondering if the '../Login' and '../Metrics' could be the cause. I will check that when I get this project migrated to a server (LONG story.) If that's the case I will mark your original answer as accepted. Otherwise I will probably have to work through it the hard way until I find the problem. I'll update this if that's so. Thanks again!